Socket keeps connecting and disconnecting in Flask socket.io
I am using Flask-socket.io. It works on local perfectly without any warning and error, but it keeps connecting and disconnecting in server. so first time it is not getting notification cause connection keeps connecting and disconnecting.
This is frontend code.
  <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.7.5/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-2huaZvOR9iDzHqslqwpR87isEmrfxqyWOF7hr7BY6KG0+hVKLoEXMPUJw3ynWuhO" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    // initialize socket for notification
    const socket = io('/notification');
    ...

And this is backend code
    app = create_app()
    babel = Babel(app, locale_selector=get_locale)
    mail = Mail(app)
    socketio = SocketIO(app)
    socketio.init_app(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")

    @socketio.on('connect', namespace='/notification')
    def handle_connect():
        if current_user.is_authenticated:
            join_room(current_user.username)
            print('connected to', current_user.username)
    return True

    @socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/notification')
    def handle_disconnect():
        if not current_user.is_authenticated:
            leave_room(current_user.username)
            print("disconnected")
    return True

This is error.

Can anyone help me this? I am really appreciate. Thanks.

The server logs will give you more clues about the failures. Also see the troubleshooting section of the Flask-SocketIO documentation to learn how to configure additional logging.
